# How can I stop a HTML checkbox from getting focus on click?

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone know how to prevent an HTML checkbox from getting focus when clicked? I still want it to change state, just not get focus.

Comment: Did you mean bordered outline as focus here?

Comment: Nope, I don't want it to take focus away from another field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can prevent the focus by using preventDefault() in a mousedown handler:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').mousedown(function (event) {
    // Toggle checkstate logic
    event.preventDefault(); // this would stop mousedown from continuing and would not focus
});
```

In pure JavaScript:

```
checkbox.onmousedown = function (event) {
    // Toggle checkstate logic
    event.preventDefault(); // this would stop mousedown from continuing and would not focus
}
```

Comment: Cool. The checkbox still changes state so that works nicely. Tx.

Answer (score 1):

#### Give this CSS:

```
input {outline: 0;}
```

But be aware that when you move control using <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, it won't be possible to identify which control are you in currently.

#### Update #1

Use this JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    this.blur();
});
```

Comment: That will just hide the fact that the checkbox has focus. I don't want the checkbox to get focus at all if possible.

Comment: There are other ways to focus of checkbox other than click.

Comment: update#1 fixed the problem